How do I configure NLog to only create a new log file once a week or month?
I've used NLog for years and it's worked well for daily logs on high-frequency processes.
I've now got a slower running process that's logging any errors and I'd like the file to only rollover once a week or month so I can more easily scan all the data in one read.
How exactly do I configure that? I tried ArchiveEvery="Month" but it just kept creating a new file every day.
Here's the current file -
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="systemLogTarget"
            archiveEvery="Month"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} - ${uppercase:${level}} - ${message} ${exception:format=stacktrace:separator=\r\n\t}" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger minlevel="Debug"
            writeTo="systemLogTarget" />
</rules>


Please update your question with your current NLog.config. Notice that NLog FileTarget does not support mixing dynamic and static archive logic

You are mixing dynamic and static archive logic. It is not supported to use archiveEvery="Month" together with fileName=".../${shortdate}.log". Maybe just remove archiveEvery="Month" and change to fileName=".../${date:format=yyyy-MM}.log" ?

Rolf Kristensen was correct in his comment.
By putting the shortdate in the filename, I was creating a dynamic log, which was overriding the archiveEvery property.
I switched by removing the log file, giving a naming scheme, and keeping archiveEvery="Month"
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="systemLogTarget"
            archiveEvery="Month"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt"
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.{###}.txt"
            layout="${longdate} - ${uppercase:${level}} - ${message} ${exception:format=stacktrace:separator=\r\n\t}" />
</targets>

